# Cloud formation init is not installing yum as subscription-manager is not registered during execution

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I am trying to launch a instance with CloudFormation Template. Instance was created-but the UserData section . configSets command to install `growpart` utility was not installed. Upon investigating (credits to @markb @marcin )the `cfn-init-cmd.log` and `cfn-init.log` it appears that the subscription-manager was not registered and attached thus not allowing the package to install.

When I `ssh` into the instance, subscription-manager is in current status. I am suspecting the subscription-manager is getting attached after the cloud formation init is executed (and fails due to this reason). I am unable to delay the execution of the cloud formation init commands as I don’t know what can be used as a wait trigger. I am unable to issue subscription-manager register and auto attach command before the grow parts install command as I don’t have the user name and password credentials so kind of struck and looking for a work around. Appreciate if anyone has suggestion to this matter

OS - `Rhel 8.5`

```
  MST01:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
    Metadata:
      AWS::CloudFormation::Init:
        configSets:
          config:
            - grow_part
        grow_part: 
          commands:
            01_install_gp:
              command: yum -y install cloud-utils-growpart
    Properties:
      IamInstanceProfile: !If 
        - UseIAM
        - !Ref IAMInstanceProfile
        - !Ref 'AWS::NoValue'
      InstanceType: !Ref InstanceType
      ImageId: !Ref AMI
      SubnetId: subnet-7654321
      SecurityGroupIds: !Ref SecurityGroups
      UserData: !Base64
        Fn::Sub: |
          #!/bin/bash -xe
          export {http,https,HTTP,HTTPS}_{proxy,PROXY}=http://proxy.company:8080
          mkdir -p /opt/aws/bin
          wget -O /tmp/aws-cfn-bootstrap-py3-latest.tar.gz https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-examples/aws-cfn-bootstrap-py3-latest.tar.gz
          python3 -m easy_install --script-dir /opt/aws/bin /tmp/aws-cfn-bootstrap-py3-latest.tar.gz
          if ! /opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource MST01 --configsets config --region ${AWS::Region}; then
              /opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? \
                   --stack ${AWS::StackName} \
                   --resource MST01 \
                   --region ${AWS::Region}
          fi
```

```
> cfn-init-cmd.log

2022-03-20 01:21:16,107 P18286 [INFO] Command 01_install_agent
2022-03-20 01:21:16,832 P18286 [INFO] -----------------------Command Output-----------------------
2022-03-20 01:21:16,832 P18286 [INFO]   Updating Subscription Management repositories.
2022-03-20 01:21:16,833 P18286 [INFO]   Unable to read consumer identity
2022-03-20 01:21:16,833 P18286 [INFO]
2022-03-20 01:21:16,833 P18286 [INFO]   This system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register.
2022-03-20 01:21:16,833 P18286 [INFO]
2022-03-20 01:21:16,833 P18286 [INFO]   Error: There are no enabled repositories in "/etc/yum.repos.d", "/etc/yum/repos.d", "/etc/distro.repos.d".
```

```
> cfn-init.log

2022-03-20 01:21:15,708 [DEBUG] CloudFormation client initialized with endpoint https://cloudformation.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
2022-03-20 01:21:15,708 [DEBUG] Describing resource MST01 in stack TEST-Clusterlog-20220318
2022-03-20 01:21:16,103 [INFO] -----------------------Starting build-----------------------
2022-03-20 01:21:16,104 [DEBUG] Not setting a reboot trigger as scheduling support is not available
2022-03-20 01:21:16,105 [INFO] Running configSets: config
2022-03-20 01:21:16,106 [INFO] Running configSet config
2022-03-20 01:21:16,107 [INFO] Running config grow_part
2022-03-20 01:21:16,107 [DEBUG] No packages specified
2022-03-20 01:21:16,107 [DEBUG] No groups specified
2022-03-20 01:21:16,107 [DEBUG] No users specified
2022-03-20 01:21:16,107 [DEBUG] No sources specified
2022-03-20 01:21:16,107 [DEBUG] No files specified
2022-03-20 01:21:16,107 [DEBUG] Running command 01_install_agent
2022-03-20 01:21:16,107 [DEBUG] No test for command 01_install_agent
2022-03-20 01:21:16,834 [ERROR] Command 01_install_agent (yum -y install cloud-utils-growpart) failed
2022-03-20 01:21:16,834 [DEBUG] Command 01_install_agent output: Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Unable to read consumer identity

This system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register.
```

Comment: "Yum is not working" is not specific. What exactly is happening? What errors do you get?

Comment: You need to look around in `/var/log` for the log output from cloud init. Possibly in `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log`.

Comment: @MarkB let me look the log and report back. I was not aware of this. Thanks for pointing

Comment: @Marcin I did not see any errors in the console output. Let me look at the error logs as MarkB suggested and report back

Comment: I ran the command via ssh `subscription-manager identity` and returns valid information. And I was able to run the `yum install command`. How do I get across this error? came across this https://access.redhat.com/solutions/78153, which seems to be old and I am able to run `yum update` with no symptoms mentioned in the kb

Comment: to perform the registration, username and password is required, which unfortunately, I dont have. How to wait for the subscription manager to be registered and attached before `yum install` is ran? Any thoughts?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.